# Used PDF BOX to convert PDF (Multiple pages with mixed orientation) to PostScript, but while printing the Auto Oritenation of PDF is Lost

Tags: pdfbox, postscript

Used PDF BOX to convert PDF (Multiple pages with mixed orientation) to PostScript, but while printing the Auto Oritenation of PDF is Lost.

If I directly Print PDF it prints fine with mixed Orientation, but not with PostScript file

Any Clues how to set Auto Orientation feature to PostScript file using PDFBOX 2

Comment: Kindly post some of your efforts, then only we can help you.

Comment: Ok, Let me ask a another question first - How to send User Federated ID to Print Jobs ?  Our Printers are RIcoh and SSO ENabled, user's swipe the ID card and take printouts - How to send the user ID  of the end user to Printer using Code

Comment: PDF doens't have an 'auto orientation' feature, each page has its own orientation. If you want to print landscape and portrait pages to a physical pritner, it must, clearly, have both portrait and landscape media, whether you can switch between them is debatable. These are device-dependent features and device-independent PostScript (which is what you'll get if you don't print to a specific device driver) won't contain any such requests. Neither this nor your comment above are PostScript questions as they stand, neither are they programming questions see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic